# Py.Test silently skips tests with errors in them using PyDev/Eclipse?

Tags: pydev, pytest

I've been looking in to using Py.Test to automate unit testing in some code I've been working on. I've discovered the following behavior: when a test that I've built has an error (that would otherwise cause the interpreter to barf), the testing framework seems to silently ignore the test altogether.

I'm worried that, as I implement more tests, I'll mistake "this test had an error and didn't run" for "this test passed". Ideally, I'd like to hit a button in Eclipse and have a unit test fail if it has a syntax error in it. Other than "Why don't you write code without syntax errors in it?", is there another solution I'm missing?

Alternatively, is there a way to make Py.Test tell you what test files were found, and which ones were run?

Setup is PyDev 2.7.1 and Eclipse 4.2, with Python 2.7.3 and PyTest 2.3.4.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the issue has to do with one of the command line options I set in Preferenced -> PyDev -> PyUnit. I had been running with `-n 4`, which splits the tests up over processors. This seems to have suppressed the syntax errors. The same option also made debugging not work (i.e., breakpoints were skipped) which seems pretty obvious in hindsight.